# How to simplify a big if statement in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Current in my code, if statement is too big and many repetitions.

```
if (!String.Equals(node.Name, "A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
 && !String.Equals(node.Name, "B", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
 && !String.Equals(node.Name, "C", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
 &&  ...
```

I would like to make it concise.
But my idea is only to create a function and passing List or Array as param.

```
List<String> target = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C" ... };
MultipleStringCompare(node.Name, target, , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Is there any more beautiful way to make it simple without making any function in modern C# syntax?

Comment: Is the comparison limited to single characters, or these may be any strings?

Comment: You can try comparing with DEC ASCII codes instead of characters

Comment: @VillageTech "A", "B", "C" are just an example. not limited to single characters.

Comment: Another option is to see which list is smaller (the ones which shouldn't be equal or the ones which should be) and take the smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest will be a `HashSet<string>`. This becomes more evident as you get into the hundreds or thousands or more of strings to compare against. Think a list of profane words, or a list of customer email addresses, etc. Unlike a one-off LINQ query with a temporary list or array, the set you create will be queried super fast and can be mutated if you desire to add even more words at runtime if you want. You could wrap this in a function, but doing a `strings.Contains(...)` is so easy it may not be worth it.

The following snippet also takes care of making every comparison case-insensitive so you don't have to think about it every time you do a string compare.

```
// create a fast lookup for strings using a case-insensitive set
HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
if (strings.Contains(node.Name))
{
    // string exists, do logic...
}

// later you can add or remove strings if you want...
// strings.Add("E");
// strings.Remove("A");
```

Comment: I think this is the best option whereas LINQ didnt' work in .NET Core 2.1..

Answer (score 2):

Yep, there's a way to do that using LINQ's functions.

The `All` function checks if **all** elements match the condition.

The `Any` function checks if **at least one** element matches the condition.

So in your case, your code will look like this

```
var result = !target.Any(str => string.Equals(node.Name, str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a LINQ statement:

```
string[] comparisons = { "A", "B", "C" ... };
bool noMatch = comparisons.All(n => !String.Equals(node.Name, n, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

If `noMatch` is true, this is equivalent to your `if` statement being true.
This assumes the strings you're comparing to are in the `comparisons` array.

How this works:

`.All()` is a LINQ extension method that takes a predicate as an input. This function will return `true` if the passed predicate returns true for every iteration. The predicate takes a single string and returns a boolean. So this is effectively equivalent to:

```
bool noMatch = true;
foreach (string n in comparisons)
{
    if (!String.Equals(node.Name, n, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        continue;
    noMatch = false;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) method in LINQ:

```
string s = "A";
!(new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" }).Any(x => String.Equals(x, s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: @Orace Well, OP said that the comparison targets are not limited to single characters anyway, so the regex approach wouldn't work in the first place. I'll edit it out

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var toAvoid = new []{"A", "B", "C"};
var isNameNotInToAvoid = !toAvoid.Contains(node.Name,
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

if(isNameNotInToAvoid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest:

```
if ("ABCDEFG".Contains(node.Name.ToUpper()))
    ;// things to do if node.Name is in string "ABCDEFG"
```

or, in case of not only single characters comparison:

```
if ("AB|CDE|F|G|HIJK|L".Split('|').Any(c => String.Equals(node.Name, c.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    ;// things to do if node.Name is one of "AB", "CDE", "F", "G", "HIJK", "L"
```